# How to define my own js function in jsfiddle?

Tags: javascript

I want to test how my own function `update` works on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/radek/cguQR/2/) but when I click the button I get an error that update is not defined.

**How can I use my own functions on jsfiddle?**

Comment: Posting code wouldn't help as I selected wrong option where my function will appear.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Two problems:

The first problem is that you have some extra text at the end of the script:

```
})();
```

The second problem is that you are wrapping the function definitions inside the `onDomReady`function.

Change this option to `no wrap(head)` and it will work.

Comment: I cannot find the extra text but the option `no wrap(head)` worked nicely. Thank you. I was trying all options and left onDomReady in my example.

Comment: Hm, I deleted the text after I saved my jsfiddle. That's why I didn't have the extra text on my screen.

Comment: I didn't understood what  no wrap(head) is. Please can you explain?